# Collatz conjecture— finite state machine transducer construction, origination?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, computer-science, open-problems, automata-theory

wikipedia has an entry on the [Collatz conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) with a section on [As an abstract machine that computes in base two](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture#As_an_abstract_machine_that_computes_in_base_two). this apparently describes a construction of a [FSM transducer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_state_transducer) computing sequential iterates starting from lsb to msb (least sig. bit to most sig. bit). [this is more a TCS, theoretical computer science construction.] however, there is no specific ref cited.

> does anyone know where this FSM iterate transducer construction appears, or first appeared in the literature?

note, there is some relation to ref [4].

<sup>[ps, have some apparently new/possibly groundbreaking results related to this construction & intend to write it up on a blog, may edit this post later to incl the ref.]</sup>

[1] [The ultimate challenge: the 3x+1 problem](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821849409), Lagarias

[2] [what is the nearest problem to the collatz conjecture that has been successfully resolved](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/11611/what-is-the-nearest-problem-to-the-collatz-conjecture-that-has-been-successful), tcs.se

[3] [The 3x + 1 Problem: An Annotated Bibliography](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0309224.pdf), Lagarias, arxiv

[4] Jeffrey O. Shallit and David W. Wilson (1991), The “3x + 1” Problem and Finite Au- tomata, Bulletin of the EATCS (European Association for Theoretical Computer Sci- ence), No. 46, 1991, pp. 182–185.

Comment: I'm afraid that self-advertisement is something particularly frowned upon here. Why not try math.stackexchange.com? The answer to your question is that the equivalence between the Collatz function and the one described in base 2 is obvious, and needs no reference.

Comment: the point is, is there a ref, in the literature, ie `reference-request`, which further explores properties of its construction etc.

Comment: I don't see he is advertising anything. He just wants a reference for the automaton formulation. 

Comment: Actually I take it back.  I didn't notice the small print on my IPhone but now that I see it on a real computer I noticed the small print.  So I upvote wccanard's comment.

Comment: no "advertising" in the post. teasing maybe? what exactly is an "advertisement"? is this just a unspoken social taboo/stigma or is there actually anything about it in official site policy? (or would that be awkward policy?) really do just want to know the state of literature on the subj & any experts knowledge of that. here is some more bkg in [cs chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2710/2013/3/2). hope to hear from anyone interested in collatz or interested in an apparently fundamentally new approach

Comment: If you would like to avoid problems of this kind, just do not refer to your work as "possibly groundbreaking" and there is no need to stress that the work is "apparently new". Why not *only* say that you are in the process of writing something related to this and thus would be interested in a reference you can quote. 

Comment: so, it appears from meta-oriented comments the off-the-books culture/convention is at odds with the on-the-books policy [from experience, a not uncommon on stack exchanges]. think the statement of the question above is quite straightforward and the contested section falls under "provide background and motivation". http://mathoverflow.net/howtoask#motivation

Comment: No, there is no discrepancy to be inferred! I said you should only say that you are writing something related to this (perhaps phrased in slightly nicer form than I sketched). As opposed to saying you should have left the ps away completely. The problem is not that you say you are writing something, but that you include some positive self-evaluation of it that, frankly, seems possibly exaggerated but even if it is not is is *irrelevant* to know whether (you think) this is "possibly groundbreaking." Indeed, *I* gave you some credit for including motivation, else it'd be closed already.   

Comment: possibility of it being groundbreaking seems to have increased with maybe no related research in the area... (the two are tied/coupled hence the statement as above)... maybe the bar is low.. but, agreed that this culture definitely regards something about self-citation as controversial/frowned on, splitting the vote with currently 6pro and 6con.... guess I will have to scan piles of meta msgs if attempting to determine the difference between legitimate self-citation/bkg/motivation and "advertising". strangely, though, dont really have any product to sell...

Comment: it appears the FSM transducer for this problem may be unpublished. a Collatz FSM transducer, some more details, ruby code, & two nearby refs are given on this blog page, the Shallit+Wilson ref already listed, and Sinyor. http://vzn1.wordpress.com/code/collatz-conjecture-experiments/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I gave a sequential machine computing the 3n+1/n:2 function in base 2 in several courses
since 1990, but of course I am not claiming any originality here, since it is just an easy
exercise.
Anyway, if you want to see in more details how this sequential machine can be computed in a systematic way, you can look at http://www.liafa.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~jep/PDF/Exposes/Sequential.pdf, slide 59.